# Active Cells of Excel In RExcel

Tags: r, rexcel

Cells in MS-Excel are always actives. Formulas update automatically when any value is modified. In **R-Excel**, I put data into R array/Dataframe and use it in a formula, and get the output.

When I change any data, I have to do all steps again to get the modified result. I want to do it automatically without writing any macros as excel does. I may do it to create an excel macro, but I don't want to.

Or how to keep data into **R-Excel** in active cell, so R may take the current value of every variable for every run/execution of R-commands.

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

RApply should do what you want.